# Smaller macron use in \section

Tags: sections-paragraphs

I achived generating smaller macrons thanks to Tobi's code from [Question 263549](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263549), but Latex throws "Undefined control sequence" if I try to use it in \section, \subsection and so on. How can I make the command \smartmacron (code follows) work in headings?

```
\newlength\tmp
\newcommand{\smartmacron}[1]{%
   \settowidth{\tmp}{#1}%
   \makebox[\tmp][c]{%
      \rule[1.2ex]{0.6\tmp}{0.035em}%
   }\kern-\tmp#1%
}
```

Mnot-WE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\newlength\tmp
\newcommand{\smartmacron}[1]{%
   \settowidth{\tmp}{#1}%
   \makebox[\tmp][c]{%
      \rule[1.2ex]{0.6\tmp}{0.05em}%
   }\kern-\tmp#1%
}
\begin{document}
  \section{\smartmacron e}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't get the "undefined control sequence" error with your mwe, but I can see a potential problem with the fragile definition of `\smartmacron` which would need protecting (or define robustly). For example `\section{\protect\smartmacron e}`.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Thanks, this helped a lot and already solved the problem! Can you provide any link on how to define it robustly, as you suggested? I don't really know what this means…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LaTeX kernel provides `\DeclareRobustCommand` which can be used to define a robust command. If you use this you don't need to protect the command in a [moving argument](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/fragile.html) (such as the argument to `\section`).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\newlength\tmp
\DeclareRobustCommand{\smartmacron}[1]{%
   \settowidth{\tmp}{#1}%
   \makebox[\tmp][c]{%
      \rule[1.2ex]{0.6\tmp}{0.05em}%
   }\kern-\tmp#1%
}
\begin{document}
  \tableofcontents
  \section{\smartmacron e}
\end{document}
```

The `etoolbox` package provides `\newrobustcmd` as an alternative to `\DeclareRobustCommand` that issues an error (rather than an easily-missed information message) if the command is already defined, which is safer:

```
\newrobustcmd{\smartmacron}[1]{%
   \settowidth{\tmp}{#1}%
   \makebox[\tmp][c]{%
      \rule[1.2ex]{0.6\tmp}{0.05em}%
   }\kern-\tmp#1%
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Defining `\let\=\smartmacron` one can overwrite the ordinary macron with this adaptive version, so that the usual `\=` calls the new defined function.