# combination of macron and breve diacritics

Tags: symbols

I try to combine the macron and the breve accent. [This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/263549) already helped me to get a good adaptive macron, and the \u command produces a nice breve, but I have problems combining them.

How can I combine them cleanly or – better – how can I draw a breve like \u produces combined with the \supersmartmacron macron (see link)?
Thank you a lot for helping me out!

PS: I am aware of \textbrevemacron from the tipa package, but it's just ugly in combination with \usepackage{mathpazo}.

### Edit 1

Thanks to Alenanno I found a good way for stacking diacritics in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159291/multiple-diacritics-on-one-character):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}
\stackon[3pt]{\={a}}{\u{}}
\end{document}
```

This produces nice combinations of the \= and \u diacritics (using the selected font, which \textbrevemacron does not → "ugly" – sorry for not pointing that out), **but**: Especially with the \i it gives a rather oversized symbol. That is what \supersmartmacron does, it creates a macron which length depends on the character width.
Is there a way to scale \u down a little bit?

MWE for the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\stacktype{L}
\stackon[1.5pt]{\={\i}}{\u{}}
\end{document}
```

Thank you!

### Edit 2

Another problem of the solution with stackengine is that the distance needs to be specified. The above example works well with fontsize=12pt only, for greater or smaller symbols it's necessary to adjust the value.

Comment: U+E537 is private use area so not generally defined as a character,  Is that really the codepoint that you mean?

Comment: unicode U+1DCB and U+1DCC are COMBINING BREVE-MACRON and COMBINING MACRON-BREVE  a᷋ a᷌

Comment: Have you seen this question? [Multiple diacritics on one character](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159291/4778)

Comment: Also, define "ugly": is the accent too low? high? Ugly is a very vague and unreliable concept.

Comment: It doesn't appear here:-) It would be relevant for latex if you were using unicode input eg `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` as the private use area characters are unlikely to be defined in that case,

Comment: @dessert -- unfortunately, it is not true for everyone that private use area characters appear correctly; they certainly don't for me.  pua characters are closely tied to particular fonts, and without "private" agreements, are unlikely to be reliable.

Comment: @dessert -- this is why i've been working very hard to get unicode extended so that use of the pua for math is minimized.  (this is a major part of the stix project: http://www.stixfonts.org ; it's been a long slog.)

Comment: The characters in the question render as subscript upper-case P, and some sort of hybrid between a penguin and a flower, for me. Please do not transmit PUA characters over the wire, ever. They are private for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining egreg's version with the adaptive macron:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\brevemacron}[1]{%
 \settowidth{\tmpa}{#1}% width of letter
 \leavevmode
 \vbox{\offinterlineskip
 \ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr
  \u{}\cr\noalign{\kern-1ex}% upper diacritic
  \rule{0.6\tmpa}{0.05em}\cr\noalign{\kern0.1ex}% lower diacritic: a bar with the legth of 0.6 times the letter width and a thickness of 0.05em, 0.1ex above the character
  #1\cr% character
  }%
 }%
}
```

[image: v0.1]

Scaling of the upper diacritic relative to the character width can be achieved with the graphicx package by changing the relevant line to

```
\resizebox{0.8\tmpa}{!}{\u{}}\cr\noalign{\kern-1.1\tmpa}% upper diacritic: \u with the width of 0.8 times the letter width
```

[image: v0.2]

Scaling the breve down just for the letter \i can be done with the xstring package, the \u line then reads

```
\IfStrEq{#1}{\i}{\resizebox{0.8\tmpa}{!}{\u{}}\cr\noalign{\kern-1.1\tmpa}}{\u{}\cr\noalign{\kern-1ex}}% upper diacritic: scaled down \u just for \i
```

[image: v0.3]
Thank you for helping me out!

Answer (score 4):

You may want to build it by hand:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\brevemacron}[1]{%
  \leavevmode
  \vbox{\offinterlineskip
    \ialign{\hfil##\hfil\cr
      \u{}\cr\noalign{\kern-1ex}
      \={}\cr\noalign{\kern-1ex}
      #1\cr
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\brevemacron{a}\u{a}\={a}

\brevemacron{a}\brevemacron{e}\brevemacron{\i}\brevemacron{o}\brevemacron{u}

\brevemacron{A}\brevemacron{E}\brevemacron{I}\brevemacron{O}\brevemacron{U}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped me a lot building my own version!

Comment: I used your macro to build stacked diacritics with Linux Libertine italics (macron + acute). Both were set too much to the right, so it was possible to move the macron a little with `\hskip0.3ex \=` (and then the acute the same). It is also possible with Unicode Combining Diacritical marks, for example k and U+0311 which poses problems for Libertine.

Comment: As this seems applicable to any font, this looks like a great workaround for stacked diacritics in general and got me quite far without having to tinker with the font-files. Are you willing to enhance your answer regarding some explanation what you did after ´\vbox´, @egreg? I only understand very little after that, and I guess this could be of great general interest. Certain combinations of letters+diacritics looked so terrible, I spent much time on font-selection before I found this.

Comment: @Kubo It’s a streamlined version of `\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}\breve{}\\[-1ex]\={}\\[-1ex]#1\end{tabular}`, with `\arraystretch` set to 0.